# Float as DateTime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008

I almost have, I think, what I'm looking to do. I'm just trying to fine tune the result.  I have a table that stores timestamps of all transactions that occur on the system. I'm writing a query to give an average transaction time.  This is what I have so far:

```
With TransTime AS (
  select endtime-starttime AS Totaltime 
    from transactiontime
   where starttime > '2010-05-12' and endtime < '2010-05-13')
Select CAST(AVG(CAST(TotalTime As Float))As Datetime) 
  from TransTime
```

I'm getting the following result:

**1900-01-01 00:00:00.007**

I can't figure out how to strip the date off and just display the time, 00:00:00:007.  Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's that first subtraction that's your problem, and why are you casting the result to DATETIME (or even TIME)?

```
With TransTime AS 
(
    -- get time in milliseconds
    select DATEDIFF(ms, starttime, endtime) AS Totaltime 
        from transactiontime
        where starttime > '2010-05-12' and endtime < '2010-05-13'
)
Select AVG(CAST(TotalTime As Float)) AS average_time_in_msec
    FROM TransTime
```

Comment: That's why I started coming to this site!   That did the trick.  Hadn't thought about Datediff.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You want to cast as a [TIME](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx).

```
With TransTime AS (
  select endtime-starttime AS Totaltime 
    from transactiontime
   where starttime > '2010-05-12' and endtime < '2010-05-13')
Select CAST(AVG(CAST(TotalTime As Float))As TIME(7)) 
  from TransTime
```

Comment: That gives me the following:

Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Explicit conversion from data type float to time is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `DATEPART` function to do this.  Check out the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

Comment: A tad confusing, but I'm reading through that documentation now.